# nested decisions for python both letter and number

Tags: python

If the character is an alphabet, then it should check if it is a vowel or consonant.
If it is a vowel, then print "Vowel".
If it is a consonant, then it should print "Uppercase" if it is in uppercase and "Lowercase" if otherwise.
If the character is numeric then it should check the value.
If it is less than 5, then print "First-half".
If it is greater than or equal to 5, then print "Second-half".
Print "Others" if input is neither an alphabet or a numeric.

i dont know how to code it because i cant figure out what syntax to use to be able to make the character alphabet or a number

the outcome i exect is either of this 6

ex 1.
enter a character: A
vowel

ex 2.
Enter a character : B
Uppercase

ex 3.
Enter a character : b
Lowercase

ex 4.
Enter a character: (lower than 5)
first half

ex 5.
Enter a character :(higher or equal to 5)
secon half

ex 6.
Enter a character : (neither alphabet or number)
other

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You already coded it in plain English... just translate exactly your description in a few `if ... elif ... else ...`. You will see it's surprisingly straightforward

Comment: Useful string functions for this are `.isdigit()` ,`.isalpha()`, `.lower()`, `.upper()`

Comment: Whatever you do don't try to make a one-liner like `('vowel' if c.lower() in 'aeiou' else 'uppercase' if c.isupper() else 'lowercase') if c.isalpha() else ('first half' if c < '5' else 'second half') if c.isdecimal() else 'other'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def check(my_char):

    if my_char.isalpha():

        if my_char.lower() in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
            print("Vowel")

        else:
            if my_char.isupper():
                print("Uppercase")

            else:
                print("Lowercase")

    elif my_char.isnumeric():

        if int(my_char) < 5:
            print("First-half")

        else:
            print("Second-half")

    else:
        print("Other")


check("A")
```

Comment: yow rymanso thanks i just tweaked a litted the code you gave me and it worked here is the code if you want to check it out

char = input("Enter a character: ")

if char.isalpha():

        if char.lower() in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
            print("Vowel")

        else:
            if char.isupper():
                print("Uppercase")

            else:
                print("Lowercase")

elif char.isnumeric():

        if int(char) < 5:
            print("First-half")

        else:
            print("Second-half")

else:
        print("Other")